# Cannot link CSS and HTML file in NetBeans

Tags: css, html, netbeans

Beginning to learn HTML and CSS for a project, however, I cannot for the life of me get my CSS file and HTML file to link up in NetBeans. They are in the same folder!

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css"/>
    <title>View Products</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li> HOME </li>
                <li> QUANTITY TO PURCHASE </li>
                <li> HTML test </li>
            </ul>   
        </nav>
        <div>
            <h1> View Products </h1>
        </div>
    </body>
```

test.css:

```
body {
    background-color: powderblue;
}
h1 {
    color: blue;
}
```

Any help is appreciated,

Cheers

Comment: if you open the folder in explorer and double click on index.html, does the style get applied to the page?

Answer (score 0):

After much frustration I found out that in my Server class (using Jooby) I have forgotten to include assets("/**"), thank you for all who took the time to read my post!

Answer (score 0):

Please check in that same folder...